# Fourth moment of Z - why does this not work

Tags: probability

I thought I could find $E(Z^4) = Var(Z^2)+E(Z^2)^2$ from the variance formula using $X$ as $Z^2$ (std normal square).  i got $Var(Z^2) = 2$ because it's a 1 degree of freedom chi square and $E(Z^2)^2 = 1$ because $E(Z^2)=1$. So it should equal 3. but when i was told that $E(Z_i^4) = 6$, where $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me and also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) agrees with you.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth moment of a normal should be 3 not 6.

Here is the rule,

For a standard normal, the odd moments are always 0.

The even moments (i.e. when m is even) are given by $2^{(-m/2)} \frac{m!}{(m/2)!}$

So if you plug in $m = 4$ you will get 3 not 6.